# Merge Operations by using spark-bigquery-connector

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, databricks, spark-bigquery-connector

Just wondering, if anyone can suggest how can we perform / Implement

1. Merge Operation
2. SCD

by using **spark-bigquery-connector**

I know we can have overwrite and append modes but not sure if overwrite truncate and re-insert or if it's a merge.

Comment: As per the [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/85a0ca2a6f67850ac39426eea679864ab3edf1a3/connector/src/main/scala/com/google/cloud/spark/bigquery/BigQueryWriteHelper.scala#L55) source code, Overwrite mode will perform `WRITE_TRUNCATE` ie.truncate existing rows and then insert new rows.

Comment: is there anyway to Perform merge instead of WRITE_TRUNCATE

Comment: There is no mode which performs merge directly, although you can join/merge the tables manually in your code. For example refer to this [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html). 
Could you provide some sample data on how you want to implement SCD ie. input data and expected output?